# Unable to style HTML list elements with bullet points

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS code:

```
<ul class="new">
    <li>OWNER OCCUPIED LOAN PROPERTY</li>
    <li>INVESTMENT LOAN</li>
    <li>FIRST HOME BUYER</li>
    <li>REFINANCING</li>
</ul>

.story ul {
    list-style: disc;
    margin: 0 0 26px 35px;
}
```

However, the list elements do not have a disc. I can't see why.

Comment: Where is `.story` and what does the `new` class have for a definition?

Comment: Make a jsfiddle that's broken. The isolated code above looks fine to me

Comment: try `ul.new li { display: list-item;}` <-- from inspecting the link you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: block;` is all fine and dandy, but it isn't what you're looking for.  In 'style.css' change

```
ul.new li {display: block;}
```

to

```
ul.new li {display: list-item;}
```

And the discs show up just perfectly.  If you want list-items, use list-items.  Cheers.

Comment: Great. Thanks @bowheart.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below format to give list style:

```
ul.new > li 
{ 
list-style: disc;
margin: 0 0 26px 35px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is a class `ul.new li` with CSS property `display: block`. On removing this style, the required 'disc' will be back.